# xml attached xsl and put inside html why it does not works?

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, xslt

I have index.html

```
<body>

 <div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li id="cd123">CD</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="data">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
   <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
  <catalog>
    <data>topic</data>
    <cd id="cd123">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    .....
   </catalog>
 </div>
```

using xsl from

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog.xsl

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml

Anyone could give me some code or trick that I achieved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send XML to a browser containing an xml-stylesheet processing instruction, the browser will attempt to load the stylesheet and apply it to the XML.

You can't do the same thing by putting an xml-stylesheet processing instruction in the middle of an HTML document. Perhaps it would be nice if you could. But it's wishful thinking; you're dreaming of a facility that doesn't exist.

In fact generally, trying to embed XML inside an HTML document is not a good idea; an HTML5 parser will try to massage it into HTML that it can recognise.